# jQuery - How to group multiple variables when using show() or hide()?

Tags: jquery

How can I group all the following variables into using a sigle show() or hide() instead of individual call for each please? Thanks.

```
var alertsLink = "alertsLink";
var alertsLinkId = $j("#" + alertsLink);
var modifyLink = "modifySearch";
var events = $j("#eventsPanel");
var alerts = $j("#alertsPanel");
var results = $j("div.results");

if(id == eventsLink){
    events.show();
    alerts.hide();
    results.hide();
    eventsLinkId.hide();
    alertsLinkId.show();
  }else if(id == alertsLink){
    events.hide();
    alerts.show();
    results.hide();
    alertsLinkId.hide();
    eventsLinkId.show();
  }else if(id != modifyLink){
    events.hide();
    alerts.hide();
    results.show();
    alertsLinkId.show();
    eventsLinkId.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to keep using your variables, rather than litter your code with lots of magic strings, then you can do:

```
events.add(alertsLinkId).show();
alerts.add(results).add(eventsLinkId).hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, jQuery supports [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#div1, #div2").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine selectors, like so:

```
$j("div.results, #alertsPanel")…
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(id == eventsLink){ 
    $j("#eventsPanel, #alertsLink").show(); 
    $j("#alertsPanel, div.results").hide();
}
```

---

You could do like this too :

```
$j('#eventsPanel, #alertsLink, #alertsPanel, div.results).hide();
switch (id) 
{ 
case 'eventsLink': $j("#eventsPanel, #alertsLink").show(); break;
case 'alertsLink': $j("#alertsPanel").show(); break;
default: $j("div.results, #alertsLink").show(); break;
}
```

Keeping your if/else works too ;)

Comment: i dont' want to hardcode each line as there are multiple conditions to manipulate. just wondering how to make a call using parametres rather than selectors if possible.

Comment: Thanks but using Box9's suggestion, it has been reduced to only 2 lines of code and it's a lot cleaner. :)